# Ways to name multiple pandas datafreames after joining 2 dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, naming

I have two large dataframes, what I want to do is make lots of smaller dataframaes consisting of the first dataframe joined with the first column of the second data frame. I have done this for one instance, however I am struggling to find the best way of storing all of the dataframes to be produced.

Here is the line of code for one instance

```
test=pd.concat([rxloc,RX.iloc[:,0]],axis=1)
```

where `rxloc` is my first dataframe and `RX` is my second dataframe

This works great, but I need to do this on 1377 columns (from the second dataframe). I can produce a loop to do the process, however Im having trouble with how to simply and effectively name all of the new dataframes in a loop. Im still pretty new to python and pandas so any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: This initial question has been answered, however I now want to repeat this process by appending another dataframe to one created by this line of code.

for i in range(len(list(RX))):
    all_dfs.append(pd.concat([rxloc,RX.iloc[:,i]],axis=1))

Im having some trouble with the appropriate loop here, again I want to add one column of dataframe 2 to each dataframe in the list all_dfs. Again any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: you can store to a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), with (key, vale)=(df_name,df)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop indeed to append each dataframe to a list:

```
all_dfs = []
for i in range(len(list(RX))):
    all_dfs.append(pd.concat([rxloc,RX.iloc[:,i]],axis=1))
```

And each value in the list `all_dfs` will be a different dataframe. Furthermore, the index-value of the dataframe in `all_dfs` will match with the position of the column in `RX` (in case you need to make some kind of future reference). Also, I'm using `range(len())` instead of simply `list(RX)` in case there are columns with equal names.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking to do

Comment: Cheers, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

u can use dictionary comprehension

```
all_data ={df{}.format(x):pd.concat([rxloc,RX.iloc[:,x]],axis=1) for x in range(len(RX.columns))}
```